# How to join queries on multiple data sources and page them effectively

Tags: c#, sql, database, design-patterns

Lets say i have two data sources for some entity say... Users. LDAP and custom Sql Database.
Now in my application, I have to show a page of users filtered from both databases based on some 'Where' conditions.

eg. 
PageSize = 10; rowsDataSource1= 100; rowsDataSource2=100;
show page 10 of 20, where User.birthdate > 2001

Assuming i don't want a caching layer in between, what would would be an effective strategy to achieve this?

Edit: of course we need a layer in between but does not have to be a caching layer.

Comment: what do you mean by a catching layer? the only way I can think of is to have a mapping class that will contain a list from datasource1 and datasource2 and you can do a filtering from the mapped class, but this may be inefficient as all records will be stored in memory

Comment: correct and as the number of records go in millions, this becomes virtually worse.

Comment: if the condition is not changing and stays always the same for both datasources, all what is left to do is simple selects from from sources, and aggregate (if needed) these selects.
Is it changing?

Comment: I think you are trying to do simple thing the hard way or you think it is simple while it is really complex and complicated. Simple because something can be done it doesn't mean you have to do it. if this is a commercial application I would advise you to go back to the drawing board, talk to an architect or someone who knows what he is doing. If you have a million record in your tables for sure you can afford to pay a strong architect otherwise you will f***** up your application and the price to pay is higher in the end

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have an unifying layer between the two datasources, you can either access both datasources after one another, or you enrich one datasource with the information of the other. Regarding this, I personally would rather build a facade which returns combined information as a single point of contact for the application.

Comment: the problem is when i have millions of records, then it is not viable to fetch and combine all the information before slicing and dicing the  data.

Comment: And why is a facade not feasible? You could handle fetching by condition in the facade instead of fetching all data and sifting lately.

Comment: facade is okay but how would you get page 10 rows out of 20 pages? It logically has to Union both the sources before performing the where clause.

Comment: i want a smart way of doing this, instead of pulling all the records.

Comment: If you want to sort a list of stuff by condition, somehow someone has to combine this stuff before, or you could separate your condition so that every heap of stuff gets sorted by its own conditions.

Answer (score 0):

On my knowledge I can suggest three ways.

1) Create a  Synonym of all other tables in different datasource and provide the read only access  to your normal schema and create a view use that View in your application. This is bit slower version.

2) Other is materialized view of different data source and use that as normal query.

3) Write a daily or hourly batch Job which import all the required data in your application schema and use it.